# How to load the following following json

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON. Can some kindly let me know how to process it using import org.json.simple.JSONObject. Also is it in valid format?

Looking fwd to your help.

{
    "args": [
        "IHAP",
        [
            "SUM:N1006631N"
        ],
        {
            "D": 43007
        },
        {
            "D": 42824
        },
        "LON",
        "EUR"
    ],
    "func": "RpcFunc"
}

Comment: Use one of the many libraries for JSON parsing?

Comment: this will help https://www.google.com/search?q=process+json+java

Answer (score 0):

How you process it will depend on the environment you are working in.
Most development languages/frameworks provide a facility to marshal a json string into a language native object for you to access.

Alternatively from a bash script, you can query the json using a utility like jq.

This is a link to the jq man pages:
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/

Comment: Is this a valid JSON? If so can someone explain to main how to process it with import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

Comment: So you're using Java. Have you looked at the documentation for that class?
http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONObject.html

See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp for introduction to json.